# Laravel - Handle method for job still in memory after completation

Tags: php, laravel, queue, timeout, jobs

I Have a Job in my application that is used to perform some operations on file (Copy, replace tags in word document, convert to pdf, zip files etc...). According to the file size the process can require a different amount of seconds, so at the first line of the handle method I added

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 14000);`

Just to avoid timeout errors. The problem is that despite the code is structured with a sequence of try catch so the job cannot fail, the process seems to be still in memory and not closed, even with a return at the last line of code. In fact sometimes this exception appears in my log file.

`Maximum execution time of 14000 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Maximum execution time of 14000 seconds exceeded at ...\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker.php:606)`

How can I fix this issue? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is an exception on the queue worker. The queue worker is a task that is always running and checking the queue for new jobs to process. By default the CLI max execution time (which is where the queue worker runs in) is infinite and for good reason.

The "correct" way to ensure a good timeout on your jobs is by providing a good configuration for the queue worker. There are two separate options that you should use in combination with each other: `retry_after` which is configured in your `config/queue.php` and the `--timeout=X` option of the queue worker task.

The way you'd use this is:

1. Set a reasonable timeout for your queue worker by running e.g. `php artisan queue:work --timeout=14000`
2. Determine the time in which a queue which previously failed is to be retried e.g. `retry_after => 14060` (one minute later)

This is documented in [Jobs expirations and timeouts](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts)

In addition I also recommend setting up your queue worker to ensure it is permanently running in the background. Laravel suggests using supervisor to do this but any method you choose (i.e. making a service, somehow using pm2 etc) would also be a good choice.